# relational operator in python beginners

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used this small piece of code and it showed I have a syntax error :

I am a python newbie , can anyone help me with this part of code. A very simple beginners program :

```
#display

def display(val):

    print("the number ",val)

#main program
while True:

    val = input("Enter an integer between 0 and 9 or -1 to quit") ;
    if val == '-1':
        break 
    if val <= '0' & val >= '9':
        display(val)
```

it's showing an error in ***val =< '0'*** part

sorry that was a very bad typo from my part , I will edit the question will the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\ra2\ra.2.py", line 16, in <module>
    if val <= '0' & val >= '9':
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: What error?  Please post the traceback.

Comment: Note that you can use `'0' <= val <= '9'`, since Python allows you to chain comparison operators that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if val =< '0' && val >= '9'`

should be:

`if val >= '0' and val <= '9'`,

or simplier:

`if '0' <= val <= '9'`

Comment: Aaaahhhh the _only_ one so far who found the _second_ error as well. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Wrong order. Instead of `=<` it should be `<=`:

```
val <= '0'
```

and `and` instead of `&`:

```
if val <= '0' and val >= '9':
```

Comment: This only fixes one error. There is also an `&&` in there that should be `and`

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

```
if val =< '0' & val >= '9':
```

Should be:

```
if val >= '0' and val <= '9':
```

Note the way the greater than and less than signs are, and the use of the word **and** rather than **&**.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
def display(val):

    print("the number ",val)

#main program
while True:

    val = input("Enter an integer between 0 and 9 or -1 to quit") ;
    if val == -1:
        break
    if val >= 0 and val <= 9:
        display(val)
```

Comment: it works fine on my mac. here is a screenshot showing exactly how i executed this code. http://i.imgur.com/punQRjf.png